# python: filter a nested list of strings with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to use list comprehension to filter this list:

```
inp = [['Fire 46.0.1', 'vlc 2.2.3','opt 0.9.9.10'],
       ['opt 0.9.9.11', 'notepad 6.9', 'adobe. 6.9', 'vlc 2.3.3']]
```

into

```
out = [['Fire 46.0.1', 'vlc 2.2.3',],
       ['notepad 6.9', 'adobe. 6.9', 'vlc 2.3.3']]
```

i.e. removing all the strings that start with 'opt'. I am trying something like

```
[soft for ls in inp if soft not soft.startswith('opt')]
```

But something is wrong with the syntax. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a nested list comprehension for filtering a nested list.

```
[[y for y in x if not y.startswith('opt')] for x in inp]
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
[[s for s in item if not s.startswith('opt')] for item in inp ]
```

Use `startswith` to filter out items with `opt` from the sublists